# Is there a way to explictly set nullable : false in OpenApi v3 spec properties?

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to set a property in the OpenAPI spec to be both required and nullable : false as specified in the C# I'm supplying.

I'm using NSwag v13.1.3 and NewtonSoft.Json v12.0.2 along with .Net Core 2.2

I've tried passing in various combinations using the NewtonSoft.Json and NJsonSchema.Annotations to force NotNull onto the fields however nullable : false doesn't seem to be possible in any combination.

I've also tried using NSwagStudio which generates the same code as below however nullable is not set to false in the spec.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Test {

[JsonProperty("test", Required = Required.Always)]
     public string Test { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("testnullable", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public string TestNullable { get; set; }

}
```

I would expect this to provide both a nullable : false and nullable : true to the OpenApi spec however this is what is presented:-

```
"required": [          
      "test",
      "testnullable"
          ],
"properties": {
               "test": {
                  "type": "string"
                        },
               "testnullable": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "nullable": true
              }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem so: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#null

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I read that and was of the impression that if it can set nullable : true then surely it can set nullable : false but it doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 5):

You could use `[Required]` attribute to show that this data is guaranteed.

```
[DisplayName("Location")]
    public class LocationDtoOut {

        [Required]
        public decimal lat { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal lng { get; set; }

        public LocationDtoOut(decimal lat, decimal lng) {
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me when setting tsconfig.json strict: true in an angular project with nSwag.  I had to add that attribute to any IList<T> properties on classes because by default it allowed those properties to be undefined in the auto generated typescript classes.  This created a lot of errors in the angular compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable is by default false. This is why it is not explocitely set to false.